# provider.ngAfterViewInit is not a function in Angular using ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

There is component that is activated by ngIf:

```
 <filter-dialog *ngIf="isFilterOpen()"></filter-dialog>
```

Where:

```
  isFilterOpen() {
    return FilterService.isOpen;
  }
```

Component class is:

```
export class FilterDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createFilterComponent();
  }
}
```

Why I can this error:

```
SkeletonComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: provider.ngAfterViewInit is not a function
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:32327)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:32292)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:32274)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44280)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
```

**createFilterComponent** is:

```
  createFilterComponent() {
    const concreteFilterForm = this.filterService.form;
    const concreteFilterComponent = FilterLinkReferenceDialogComponent;

    /* Factory angular */

    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      concreteFilterComponent
    );

    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    this.componentRef.instance.form = concreteFilterForm;
  }
```

Comment: please, show code of `this.createFilterComponent();`?

Comment: OKay, see my update

Comment: from where do you import AfterViewInit ? Is @Component decorator decalred properly?

Comment: Try it after `npm cache clean -f` restart server using  `ng serve`

Comment: From `{} from "@angular/core";`

Comment: I have tried to clear cache, it is the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `FilterService.isOpen` to `true`:

```
createFilterComponent() {        
    /* The code is omitted for the brevity */
    FilterService.isOpen = true;
}
```

In addition, try to restart your application by  `ng serve`

Comment: Do you mean remove ngIf from template and add this to component>

Comment: @OPV no, just this line of code and see what happens.